# npm installation in command prompt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After setting new windows in my laptop,i am trying to install npm in command prompt.But i am facing an error which picture is given in below.Would anybody help me out?

[image: npm errors]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a package to install (like `npm install -g nodemon`) npm will try to install all packages from the current package.json file. If there is non, npm will throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

Npm is already installed. That is why the error message is not *Command not found*.

The specific command you issued `npm install -g` attempts to use npm to install the package in the current directory globally.

Leaving the point that installing packages globally is a bad idea aside, this is failing because you are running the command in a directory that *does not contain a package*. It is your home directory, not one containing a `package.json` file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to install npm(node package manager) do it by downloading it from here: https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm, then you are good to go.

The command you are actually giving is to install a package using npm(check https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Thats why the error shows *could not install from ""* as you have not specified any package to install.